# How to share a google doc in template mode, and include appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

What I have: a google doc with some text and custom appscript

What I want to do: I want to provide this document as a template that others in my team can copy for their use, but cant edit the original

What I've tried: I tried using google URL tricks to do mydocURL/template/preview to provie a view  showing the template in read only, and a button 'use template'. However when clicking 'use template' it does not copy the companion appscript, only the initial text.

What I'm lookingfor: Some other URL trick, or intermediate appscript I can use to allow a team member to provide their drive share folder, and then it makes a copy to their folder?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Click the share button in the top right corner, make sure everyone has viewing permissions. I recommend setting it to "anyone with the link" and giving it viewer permissions:
[image]
Click "Copy link". Your URL should look like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/<ID>/edit?usp=sharing
```

If you are using a different service (eg. sheets), the `document` part of the url may be different, but the same concept applies.
Change the `/edit?usp=sharing` to `/copy`.

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/<ID>/copy
```

Send people that link. The result should look like this:
[image]
Any app script on the doc will also be copied and added to the project automatically, but the user will have to manually authenticate/deploy (if needed)

Comment: Does the end user become the owner of the script?

Comment: @Cooper When you copy it, you also make a copy of the script, so yes